# Polynomial $x^5 + 5x^2 +1$ is irreducible or not

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, substitution

> Which way I can determine whether the polynomial $x^5 + 5x^2 +1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ or not?

Mod $p$ Irreducibility Test and Eisenstein's criterion not applicable here.

Which way I should proceed?

Comment: You mean you cant use the mod P irreducibility or that you tried without success?

Comment: Reduce modulo $2$. Show that your new polymomial has no roots in $\Bbb Z_2$ and show that your reduced polynomial can't be written as $q(x)p(x)$ where $q$ has degree $2$ and $p$ has degree $3$.

Comment: No. Actually I tried. But then after reducing by mod5 polynomial becomes x^5 + 1 . Then I dont know  how should I check if x^5 +1 is irreducible in Z5 or not.

Comment: I second AJ Stas's advice. Reduce modulo 2. The polynomial $x^5+x^2+1$ has no zeros in $\Bbb{Z}_2$, and it is not divisible by the unique (!) quadratic irreducible either.

Comment: By the way, $x^5 + 1$ is not irreducible mod $5$ because $-1$ is a root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try $x=y-1$. It should help by the  Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: Yeah it worked!! Thanks Dear!!

Comment: @user458361 You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

$7^5+5\cdot 7^2+1 = 17053$ which is a prime number. Thus the polynomial is irreducible by [Cohn's irreducibility criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohn%27s_irreducibility_criterion).